# I want to deploy or copy the artifacts to a subfolder inside the wwwroot of azure app service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm using azure AzureWebApp@1 to publish the contents of my front end app, however it has to be deployed to a folder inside the wwwroot of the app service. I tried using the customDeployFolder but it is not working. Is there a way I can achieve this using yaml? Thanks

Comment: are you using build output? are you using YMAL based pipeline?

Comment: I'm using the yaml bases pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ [levi-lu-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11882186/levi-lu-msft) , Your answer helped lot.

You can use the **KUDU API** to deploy the azure app service outside the `wwwroot` with the artifacts. You need to add an azure `PowerShell` task in your **release pipeline** and run **kudu api**. Below scripts is for example.

**1, scripts to create a directory CustomDomain**

```
    $WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name '<appname>' -ResourceGroupName '<resourcegroupname>'
    [xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp
    
    # Create Base64 authorization header
    $username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
    $password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
    $bodyToPOST = @{
        command = "md CustomDomain"
        dir = "D:\home\site"
    }
    
    # Splat all parameters together in $param
    $param = @{
        # command REST API url
        Uri = "https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
        Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
        UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"
        Method = "POST"
        Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)
        ContentType = "application/json"
    }
# Invoke REST call
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

Above scripts will first get the username and password from your app's publishprofile which will be used later as anthentication in calling kudu api. And the api will run your self-defined command to make directory **CustomDomain** in "**d:\home\site**"

[image]

**2, Deploy your app using kudu api**.

When the CustomDomain directory is created, you can invoke kudu api to deploy your app to CustomDomain directory. Please refer to below example.

```yaml
$param = @{  
            # zipdeploy api url  
            Uri = "https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/CustomDomain"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "PUT"  
            # Deployment Artifact Path  
            InFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<artifacts_alias>\drop\<artifacts_name>.zip"  
            ContentType = "multipart/form-data"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

The value  **InFile**  should point to location of the artifact file which is downloaded by your release pipeline. Usually it is located in  `"$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<artifacts_alias>\drop\<artifacts_name>.zip"`

Refer [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149577/15997690)